# Can anybody identify these chop markings or calligraphy please (Characters identified: 季康長壽 寧復畫記)

Tags: meaning, etymology

[image]

[image]I have been given a scroll not sure if it is chinese or Japanese but I know it is over fifty years old.  I am trying to find out more about it such as the artist and what the writing says.

Answer (score 1):

the text is, my best guess:

每為惜花無曉夜・教人甚處不銷魂

two verses of a poem of 宋 dynasty

己亥 (1959 +-60i, i is integer)

季康 (the name of the author) 寫 (written)